# Error when using devtools::load_all()

Tags: r, namespaces, package, devtools

I am developing a package using `devtools`. I wanted to check my package on a different computer than the one the package was developed on to see if it works. I installed the latest R and Rstudio version, and I also installed the packages listed in the Getting Started section in Hadley Wickham's book on R packages (`install.packages(c("devtools", "roxygen2", "testthat", "knitr")`)
Then I ran `devtools::has_dev()` got `TRUE` as expected.
However when I do `devtoold::load_all()` I get the following error:

```
Error in (function (dep_name, dep_ver = NA, dep_compare = NA)  : 
  Dependency package dplyr not available.
```

This is how my `DESCRIPTION` file looks like:

```
Package: prepdat
Title:xxx
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: c(
    person("Ayala S.", "Allon", email = "ayalaallon@gmail.com", role = c("aut", "cre")),
    person("Roy", "Luria", role = "aut"),
    person("Jim", "Grange", role = "ctb"),
    person("Nachshon", "Meiran", role = "ccp"))
Description: xxxx
Depends: R (>= 3.0.3),
Imports: dplyr (>= 0.4.2),
    reshape2 (>= 1.4.1)
License: GPL-3
LazyData: true
Suggests: knitr,
    testthat
```

And this is how the `NAMESPACE` looks like:

```
importFrom(dplyr,"%>%")
importFrom(psych,"harmonic.mean")
```

Does anyone knows how can I solve this error? I want to zip my package and send it to a colleague so he can go over it using `devtools::load_all()`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best

Ayala

Comment: Your package imports dplyr and reshape2, but you didn't say you installed them...

Comment: Hey @Joshua Ulrich. Thank you for our comment. I need to install them but not load them using `library()` (just install), and then when I use `devtools::load_all()` it should work? Thanks again.

Comment: Hey again @JoshuaUlrich. I did what you suggested and it works now. However I still wonder if my `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION` files are build correctly such that when hopefully users will download my package from the CRAN it will work. Thanks again!

Comment: When a package is *installed*, its dependencies will also be installed (unless someone explicitly says not to in `install.packages`). In your test, the dependencies weren't installed because you never installed your package, you just loaded it.